# React javascript control showing/hidding items in a menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started working with react Js recently and I try to show and hide items in a menu using ternary operator. My question is how not to show the items of the menu when they are empty, in other words when i use empty {} in the code as shown in the picture. [image]

```
renderFilterActions = () => [
{
  
  type: 'menu',
  style: { marginRight: 32 },
  onClick: (action) => action(),
  disabled: this.props.exporting,
  options: [

         !getUserPrivileges().canViewArbitrationParcels
          ? {
            disabled: this.props.exporting,
            label: 'Export dlp',
            //////
          }
          : {
            disabled: this.props.exporting,
            label: 'Download Excel',
            //////////
          },
          
          {
            disabled: this.props.exporting,
            label: 'export programming',
            ///////
          },

          getUserPrivileges().canRefreshVessel ?

          {
            disabled: this.props.exporting,
            label: 'VVVVVVVVVVVVVV',
            icon: (<Dice style={{ marginLeft: 2, marginTop: 3 }} />),
            action: () => {
              this.handleVesselModalClose();
            },

          }
          :
            {},
          

          getUserPrivileges().canRefreshVessel ?
          
            {
              disabled: this.props.exporting,
              label: 'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR',
              ///////
            }
          :
            {}
          
        
    
  ],
},
{ type: 'primary', label: 'actions' , disabled: this.props.exporting },
```

];

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the library that you're using is implemented. Generally, if given a `null`, React won't render anything - but the library might still render a container with nothing in it.

The safest thing to do would be to remove the items you don't want to show from the list. One way to do this would be to return `null` in your ternary condition, and then filter out the nulls:

```
options: [
  // ---- 8< -----
  getUserPrivileges().canRefreshVessel 
    ? {
      disabled: this.props.exporting,
      label: 'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR',
      ///////
    }
    : null,
  ].filter(option => !!option),
```